# Water levels of the flood found in Exodus 14

Tags: hebrew

In Exodus 14:27, the water is at its "usual strength" (le,etano) spelled with a yud; but the water returned to its pre-set level. This "preset level" I believe can be found in the word (li,tenao) spelled with the letter hei; yet I cannot find this Hebrew word spelled with a hei anywhere else. Please help me find this word in the Tanach.  Again, one word spelled with a yud and the other spelled with a hei. Please help me locate both of these words -one with a yud and the other with a hei.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX. Thanks for your contribution. Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

The word אֵיתָן (ethan) occurs exactly 13 times in the OT as follows:

1. Gen 49:24   בְּאֵיתָן֙
2. Ex 14:27 לְאֵ֣יתָנ֔וֹ
3. Num 24:21 אֵיתָן֙
4. Deut 21:4 אֵיתָ֔ן
5. Job 12:19 וְאֵֽתָנִ֣ים
6. Job 33:19 אֵתָֽן׃
7. Ps 74:15 אֵיתָֽן׃
8. Prov 13:15 אֵיתָֽן׃
9. Jer 5:15 אֵיתָ֣ן
10. Jer 49:19  אֵיתָן֒
11. Jer 50:44  אֵיתָן֒
12. Amos 5:24 אֵיתָֽן׃
13. Micah 6:2 וְהָאֵתָנִ֖ים

Note that most of these occurrences have the letter yod but I could not find any that are spelled with a He.

Answer (score 0):

According Solomon Mandelkern (*Concordantiae* […], p. 59) the following 14 terms are all those related to the conceptual root (MT) ITN/ATN:

איתן
(AITN)

Num 24:21; Deu 21:4; Jer 5:15; 49:19; 50:44, Amo 5:24; Psa 74:15; Pro 13:15.

אתן
(ATN)

Job 33:19.

באיתן
(BAITN)

Gen 49:24.

לאיתנו
(LAITNU)

Exo 14:27.

ואיתנים
(UAITNIM)

Job 12:19.

האתנים
(EATNIM)

1 Kin 8:2.

והאתנים
(UEATNIM)

Mic 6:2.

We count 14 terms (instead of 13) because Mandelkern, as well as, Benjamin Davidson, Strong [H386>H388], Brown-Driver-Briggs, and others, linked the term of the Jewish month Ethanim - found in 1Kin 8:2 - with this same MT conceptual root ITN/ATN.

To answer directly to your question, I see only two of these occurrences containing an ה inside the term, that are האתנים (EATNIM), on 1 Kin 8:2; and והאתנים (UEATNIM), on Mic 6:2, both related to the Hebrew definite article.